# Lost default counterpart

Tags: xcode

I lost the default counterpart reference between a single pair of files, e.g. someClass.h and someClass.m. Neither someClass.m and someClass.h has a counterpart. This is a little frustrating because the shortcut cmd + ctrl + up arrow (jump to counterpart) does not work. No other classes in my project have this issue.

Is there a way of repairing (either manually or by some global reset) the counterpart reference in the project files ?

Answer (score 0):

What solved the problem for me was removing and adding back the files to the project but also the local git repository. The exact sequence was:

- doing a backup of the affected .m and .h files in a different directory
- deleting these files completely from the project (not only a reference, but -> files to trash),
- committing to my local git repository (two files removed),
- adding the files back to the project tree from the backup directory, with the option to "Copy items into destination group's folders...",
- committing again the source with two newly added files.